# Agora Always token expired when using unity Token generators

Tags: unity-game-engine, token, agora.io

I make video chatting use agora

https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/develop/integrate-token-generation?platform=unity

I made it by following the guide above.

Play UnityEditor and Create a token with a token generator and start join channel.

But Channel Join is fail and I receive "Error code:109 msg:channel key expired"

It's a new token make by token generator, but I don't know why it's being expired.

sombody help me. thx.

```
    private string appId = "my_agora_consone_appId";
    private string appCertificate = "my_agora_consone_appCertificate ";
    private string channelName = "vdch57";
    private string uid = UserInfo.Instance.userKey.ToString();
    private string userAccount = "User account";
    private int expirationTimeInSeconds = 3600; 
    public string MakeToken(string channelName)
    {
        AccessToken token = new AccessToken(appId, appCertificate, channelName, uid);
        string token2 = SignalingToken.getToken(appId, appCertificate, userAccount, expirationTimeInSeconds);
        token.addPrivilege(Privileges.kJoinChannel, Convert.ToUInt32(expirationTimeInSeconds));
        string result = token.build();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using Unity or C#, but I also tried the token generator in C#/Unity but got the same Token Expired Error.

Check this out:(you can change platform at the top)
https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/develop/authentication-workflow?platform=unity

This shows how to deploy a token server to Railway which you can send a http GET request to in order to get the rtcToken. This is their secure and recommended way so I assume it is more reliable than the local token generator you and I have used